# Assigning values to variables in mfc forms controls

Tags: variables, visual-c++, mfc, editbox

I am using MFC  visual studio 2013, i have  a form with two edit boxes,  X and Y .  I want the sum  X and Y to display in  static text box on the form when I click DISPLAY BUTTON.

X + Y = Z

X  edit box1
Y  edit box2
Z  static text box, to display result Z

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What part of getting and putting data to and from the controls are you having an issue with?

Comment: Rather than using a static box, I typically use a read-only CEdit box.  This way the end-user can select/copy the contents of the box.  You can't do a COPY operation on a static, but you can on a CEdit control.  Read Only is one of the resource flags.

Comment: You say it is MFC and yet you tag it winforms?

Comment: It MFC application, dialog .

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**In header (.h)**
Add this function in your header : This function will be called when you click

```
afx_msg void OnBnClickedDisplay();
```

**In your CPP (.cpp)**
Add listener

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStackOverFlowDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_DISPLAY, OnBnClickedDisplay) // Add listener
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This part was generated automatically for you when you have done "Add Variable"

```
void CStackOverFlowDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    // This part was generated automatically when you do "Add Variables" in Dialog part
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_x); // Here we get/set content of m_x variable From/To Edit
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_y); // Here we get/set content of m_x variable From/To Edit
}
```

**Calcul Function**

```
void CStackOverFlowDlg::OnBnClickedDisplay()
{
    
    UpdateData (TRUE);// Load Data From dialog to Variables
    
    int iResult = m_x+m_y;// Calculate Somme

    // Formatting
    CString strResult;
    strResult.Format(_T("%d"), iResult);

    // Update result on Dialog
    GetDlgItem (IDC_STATIC_RESULT)->SetWindowTextA(strResult);
}
```

Comment: A couple of things. The use of `GetDlgItem` should be avoided except for the likes of specializing `DDX` handlers. A control member should be used. Calling `UpdateData` should be avoided. If this where part of a bigger picture, other data would be unintentionally modified. Otherwise, a nice bunch of work you have done here!

Comment: @lakeweb Indeed, I agree with you. I'm not a big fan of getDlgItem and UpdateData but I just wanted to simplify things for him

Comment: You can also se GetDlgItemText. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemtexta

Answer (score 1):

Landstalker has given a good start of an answer. I'd differ from his solution in one crucial respect though.

Rather than using `GetDlgItem` to play with the value directly, I'd add a variable for the static control (the one you've given the ID `IDC_STATIC_RESULT`). It'll be just about like the `m_x` and `m_y` you've already created, but obviously with some other name (e.g., `m_z`).

Then comes a crucial point. When you associate `value` type variables with edit/static controls (or others, but those are what we care about right now), MFC uses a function named `UpdateData` to move data between the control and the associated variable. You call `UpdateData();` or `UpdateData(true);`, to copy data from the control into the associated variable. You call `UpdateData(false);` to copy data from the variable into the control.

In your button handler you'll want to do that, so it'll come out something like this:

```cpp
void CaddDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    UpdateData(); // get the data from the controls
    m_z = m_x + m_y; // compute the new value
    UpdateData(false); // push the updated data back to the controls
}
```

That works well enough in this case, but with a complex dialog, the `UpdateData` stuff can be pretty old in a hurry, especially when you have controls that interact with each other. In such a case, it's generally better to ignore the `value` variables, and just use `control` variables, which represent the control itself, so you can read and write controls individually (whereas `UpdateData` always copies values from all controls into associated variables, or vice versa).

Comment: How about performance by multiplying the number of calls to updatedata ... ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Highly appreciated. It is working.

Comment: @Landstalker: Most of the time taken by `UpdateData` is in calls to `SetWindowText`. In other words, you're pretty much just re-inventing (part of) `UpdateData`. As a more or less separate point, we're also dealing user interaction here, so as long as the dialog is updated in less than ~20 ms, it simply looks instantaneous--and `UpdateData` was fast enough , even with *far* more controls than you should display at once, running on a 25 MHz 486.